# How to Call Function with pass select to param

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that has a parameter `varchar`.

I want to call the function and pass select result to function like

```
Select * from dbo.myfunc(select name from users)
```

But I get this ERROR:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

What can I do?

Comment: Your error is because a function call needs brackets as does a subquery.  You only have one set.  However, passing a subquery to a function that has a varchar parameter is fundamentally wrong anyway.  @Parado's answer looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
select dbo.myfunc(name) from users
```

Comment: will the function be called for each and every record in the table Users?

Comment: @knkarthick24 Yes it will

Comment: @Parado I getting This ERRO :

Comment: `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.myfunc", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: Did you run my query directly without any changes?

Comment: yes , i run your query without any changes . but getting thats error

Comment: @PsarTak sql server doesn't see `dbo.myfunc` function. Are you sure `dbo.myfunc` is on the srever?

Comment: @Parado I run My function with static paramert and work fine .

Comment: @PsarTak Can you put this code with static parameter to the comment?

Comment: select * from dbo.fn_CSVToTable('my value')

Comment: @PsarTak So this is `fn_CSVToTable` not `myfunc` :). Can you run this: `select dbo.fn_CSVToTable('my value')`

Comment: @PsarTak It's no problem :) can you run the code which I put in previews comment?

Comment: @Parado I run this :`select dbo.fn_CSVToTable('my value')` And Getting This ERROR:`Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_CSVToTable", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: @PsarTak I don't know why. It should work. What is your sql-server version?

Comment: @Parado my sql server v is: 2008

Comment: @PsarTak For this version It should work. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619697/how-to-create-and-call-scalar-function-in-sql-server-2008) is similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
Select f.*
from users u cross apply
     dbo.myfunc(u.name) as f;
```

Comment: @PsarTak . . . That names the result from the function.  The `f`` is the table alias and the `. . .` are the columns.